# Die probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that a balanced die is rolled 3x, and let $X_i$ denote the number that appears on the ith roll (i=1,2,3). Evaluate:

i. P(X1>X2) = $15/2^6$

(1 - 5 way, 2- 4 ways, 3- 3 ways, 4 - 2 ways,  5 1 ways, 6 0 ways) = 15 ways/$2^6$ total ways

ii. P(X1>X2>X3)

I am not really sure...

iii. P(X1=X2) = 1/6

each number has a 1/6 chance of being rolled

iv. P(X1=X2=X3) = 1/6*1/6=1/36

v. $P(X1+X2+X3 \le 4)$ = $4/6^3$

3 1's or 2 1's (1 1 1, 2 1 1, 1 2 1, 1 1 2) = 4 ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i. is supposed to be $\frac{15}{6^2}=\frac{15}{36}=\frac{5}{12}$, not $\frac{15}{2^6}$
ii. If you pick any 3 different numbers from 1-6, every arrangement will have different numbers, which can be arranged in decreasing order to form the die rolls that meet the criteria. So, the number of arrangements that will meet the criteria is $6\mathrm{C}3$.
$6\mathrm{C}3=\frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!}=\frac{6\times5\times4}{3\times2\times1}=5\times4=20$
$\frac{20}{6^3}=\frac{20}{216}=\frac{5}{54}$

Comment: can you explain 2 again??